# Adobe DTM onClick event stopped working but works onMouseOver?

Tags: tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

We have a rule that looks for a custom HTML-5 attribute (“data-analytics-nav-name”) and captures the name assigned to that particular attribute. It stores it in a cookie and that cookie is read on the following page load by a data element and reported as prop50.

The issue is, that rule stopped working consistently approx. 2 weeks ago? I do see it working on some elements but on others where it worked previously, it stopped? The weird thing is, if I change the rule event type to be “mouseover”, it will work. As soon as I change it back to “click” it won’t work on some elements?

To duplicate issue:

1. Go to www.bankofthewest.com.
2. Click on the “Security” link on the top right of the navigation
3. Should capture the info from the HTML-5 attribute and put into “navElemName” cookie
4. Should see a value from “navElemName” in prop50 on next page

If you want to point to the staging code (which one image demonstrates ) please add "#testdtm" to the URl and refresh. This will set your local storage and DTM will load the staging code. Clear local storage when done or it will keep pointing to staging code.

Thanks!
[image: Issue Description]

[image: Event Based Rule]

Comment: I would start with [properly implementing the DTM Header/Footer code](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/code.html)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that is unfortunately out of my control and would take a small book to explain why! It has to do with 3rd parties we use.

Comment: Okay, well there is a very good chance your code isn't working because of that, soo.. not sure what else to say if you can't fix it. Bottom line is Adobe will not support improperly implemented DTM

Comment: I know what you are talking about! FYI... I'm a big fan of yours!